# Getting instances of a model in Sequelize with two associations

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, postgresql-10

I'm using Sequelize, and am not entirely sure how to get all instances of a model with conditions on two associations. Take the following setup, where individuals own many dogs and don't necessarily use the same kennel to board each one:

```
let Owner = sequelize.define('owner', ...);
let Kennel = sequelize.define('kennel', ...);
let Dog = sequelize.define('dog', ...);

Dog.belongsTo(Owner);
Dog.belongsTo(Kennel);
Kennel.hasMany(Dog);
Owner.hasMany(Dog);
```

Given an instance of a kennel and an instance of an owner, how do I find all the dogs that are owned by that owner and boarded in that kennel? Obviously if I only cared about one of those conditions, I could do `owner.getDogs()`, but I'm not sure how to generalise that.

Comment: What do we consider `that owner` and `that kennel` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are simply looking for dogs that have a certain kennel or owner. Having both instances, you will have both foreign keys

```
Dogs.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [{kennelId: kennel.id}, {ownerId: owner.id}]
  }
})
```